# Does successful form elements are submited as parameters automatically on AJAX calls?

Tags: ajax, forms, element, request.querystring

Do we have to include all **form** elements (ids and values) manually in the query string when making an **Ajax** call, or they are **automatically** (according to standard) included as parameters to the query string of the request?

Answer (score 0):

Well, since no one is eager to answer my question. I will.
the quick answer is no. by standard let's say HTML standard. form element values are not automatically submitted a long with a request as parameters, **when making an Ajax call**.
but when you submit a form by submit() function of the form element, it will include all successful elements in the query and will send it as parameters to the server.

so If you are using Ajax, you have to include every elements which you need yourself.
however there are some utility functions that can help you. like the serialize() method in Jquery framework.

have fun :)